# Please re-open this question that was closed as opinion-based or unclear

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[What has the RIAA(/MPAA/BSA) done in re the recent surge in music piracy?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/what-has-the-riaa-mpaa-bsa-done-in-re-the-recent-surge-in-music-piracy)

I changed the secondary opinion question into what it was intended to be: some elaboration of the primary [factual](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/54809/785) question.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger problem I would say is that the question is too broad and that while this site does occasionally dip into questions about the music industry, it's very hard for us to gauge current events as we are a site of fans not music industry insiders.

If the music industry was taking massive action, the interworkings of it would not be known until after the action was implemented.